# Solving linear system of equations to obtain different classes of solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Correct me if I am wrong. 
Find the value(s) of the constant $k$ such that the system of linear equations

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x + 2y = 1\\[2ex]
k^2x − 2ky = k + 2
\end{array}
\right.$$

has:

1. No solution
2. An infinite number of solutions
3. Exactly one solution

Answer:

so the first step is to get row reduction form, which is:

from $ \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 2 \\
     k^2 & -2k \\
     \end{bmatrix}$,

to $ \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 2 \\
     0 & -2k+2k^2 \\
     \end{bmatrix}$,

Comment: I think that if you are trying to solve a system of linear equations, using [augmented matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix) would be better. (I.e., you should add right-hand sides, too).

Answer (score 1):

You row reduction is wrong.  We get
$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
1&2&2\\
0&-2k^2-2k&-k^2+k+2
\end{array}$$
which is equivalent to
$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
1&2&2\\
0&2k(k+1)&(k+1)(k-2)
\end{array}$$

From here we see that there is no solution iff $k=0$, an infinite number of solutions iff $k=-1$ and else there is exactly one solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
 1. No solution when: $$\frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ 2 } } =\frac { 2 }{ -2k } \neq \frac { 1 }{ k+2 }  $$ it holds when $k=0$

2. An infinite number of solutions when :$$ \frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ 2 } } =\frac { 2 }{ -2k } =\frac { 1 }{ k+2 } $$ it holds when $k=-1$
3. Exactly one solution when:$$ \frac { 1 }{ { k }^{ 2 } } \neq \frac { 2 }{ -2k }  $$ and it hold when $k\neq -1$

Comment: can i get to kow if my row reduction form is correct?

Comment: What you have done is not clear for me,what did you get?i gave hint,recomment to use from it

Comment: so you have given me a final answer i guess?

Comment: it is a hint actually,but hope you can find from it all answers)

Comment: so the first step is to get row reduction form, which is:

from $ \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 2 \\
     k^2 & -2k \\
     \end{bmatrix}$,

to $ \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 2 \\
     0 & -2k+2k^2 \\
     \end{bmatrix}$,

Comment: is the above step correct?

Comment: What did try to do?you should find k in that cases that you mentioned,your method is not correct,i will post answer

Comment: yeah it would be better

Comment: what is the exact way to do this question?

Comment: you can solve any question with different many ways,it depends on the question,what i wrote was general solution

Answer (score 0):

Is your "row reduction form" supposed to be a matrix?

Here is how I would do this:  From $x+ 2y= 1, x= 1- 2y$.  Putting that into the second to get $k^2- 2^2y- 2ky= k+ 2$.  From that, $2k(k+ 1)y= k^2- k- 2$ so $y= (k^2- k- 2)/(2k(k+ 1))$.

As long as the denominator is not $0$, that is, as long as k is not $0$ or $-1$, there is one solution.  If the denominator is $0$, then there are either no solution (if the numerator is not also $0$) or an infinite number of solutions (if the numerator is also $0$).  If $k= 0$, the numerator is $-2$ and if $k= -1$, the numerator is $0$,

Comment: yes it is a matrix
is my reduction form correct as mentioned in the previous comment?

Comment: Please start using LaTeX, see this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Almost all of your posts (seven out of 8 answers you posted yesterday!) need heavy editing.